# Can't access(or see ) the newly created folder in ExtJs inside MyApp

Tags: javascript, extjs

So I learned that the best practice in adding global variables in Ext JS is to create a folder inside MyApp and create a new Js for it.  So this is how I did mine:

This is under **Sencha > app > global > Vars.js**

```
Ext.define('DevToolsTraining.global.Vars', {
singleton: true,

  User: {
      ID: "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}",
      runningNum: 0,
      Username: "default",
      CreatedOn: new Date(),
      Contacts: []
  }
});
```

I'm doing a Sencha project inside Visual Studio.  When I try to do DevToolsTraining in Developer Tools of Chrome I can see the folders **model**, **store**, and **view**.  Why can't I see the new folder I created?
My aim is to do **DevToolsTraining.global.Vars.User** in my code but I can't, since **DevToolsTraining.global** is **undefined**.

Comment: Have you [required](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-requires) the `DevToolsTraining.global.Vars.User` somewhere?

Comment: actually that's what I was thinking about. but when I tried requiring it inside my Main which is my viewport and  the same thing I did to my other views and models I still can't see it

Comment: Do you see the class file being loaded in the "Network" tab in Dev Tools? Are you getting any errors when initializing the app?

Comment: i don't see the files loaded in dev tools.. and there's no error.. do i need to create a controller for this??

Comment: I don't know what happened.. but when I try to transfer it from other folder, and require it to my main view port it gave me location error of undefined.. and i place it back to my folder again but didn't removed the require, it worked.. la la la la i really don't know, it's now working

Comment: anyway i have 1 question. how do i reset this session? example, I want to set the User to all these values again

Comment: why can't I access this inside a store?

Comment: Make sure it is required before the stores.. You can reset the data by using `DevToolsTraining.global.Vars.User = newUserData;`

Comment: this variables get reset when the page gets refresh?

Comment: Yes, on each page reload, you will get the "variables" that you've defined in the class declaration

Comment: oh okay, i thought it works like a session in AngularJs or ASP.NET. but many thanks for the help, I'm trying to store logged in user info into a global variable (session) which i can call anytime and anywhere i like